# SAX Parser - NumberFormatException

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

I try to parse next xml document by SAX Parser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<dance title="foxtrot" id="1">

    <type>ballroom</type>

    <scene>assembly hall</scene>

    <numberOfDancers>10</numberOfDancers>

    <music>phonogram</music>

    <dancers>
        <dancer>Ivanov Ivan</dancer>
        <dancer>Petrova Ludmila</dancer>
    </dancers>

    <number>22</number>

</dance>
```

It's in characters:

```
if (thisElement.equals("numberOfDancers")) {
     dance.setNumberOfDancers(new Integer( (new String(ch, start, length))) );
}
```

and this is what i got:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "

    "
at     java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at parsers.SAXParser.characters(SAXParser.java:58)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.characters(AbstractSAXParser.java:546)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:463)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:328)
at Main.main(Main.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)




Integer.java:569  is next:
     } else if (firstChar != '+')
                    throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s);
```

Where could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are trying to parse a substring `new String(ch, start, length)` into an Integer. NumberFormatException just saying you what it says - newline characters cannot be interpreted as a number:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "

"
```

This may occur if you have something like this in your xml:

```
...
<scene>assembly hall</scene>
<numberOfDancers>
</numberOfDancers>
<music>phonogram</music>
...
```

Check your xml input.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i haven't new line sign between tags. My xml file is exactly like in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Your element text in the variable `thisElement` is out of sync with whatever you think your current location in the xml is. From the error message it's showing that it holds a string of blanks with newlines at the point where it's expected to hold a number, where that stream of blanks is likely the element text preceding the current element.

Your characters method doesn't comply with the SAX documentation. The characters method can be called by the parser multiple times per element, you can't be sure you have the full element text until the endElement method is called. See [the Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html):

> Parsers are not required to return any particular number of characters at one time. A parser can return anything from a single character at a time up to several thousand and still be a standard-conforming implementation. So if your application needs to process the characters it sees, it is wise to have the characters() method accumulate the characters in a java.lang.StringBuffer and operate on them only when you are sure that all of them have been found.

The characters method should do nothing more than save the content in a buffer (appending to a StringBuilder, for instance). Check for the values in the endElement method (trimming whitespace before you parse it as a number), then clear the buffer.

Here is an example of how a ContentHandler can work. It keeps track of its location in the XML being read, and saves the element text as it goes until it reaches the end of an element, when it matches the text to a property of the object based on the current path:

```
class DanceContentHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private List tagStack = new ArrayList();
    private StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    private Dance dance = new Dance();

    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
    String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        buffer.clear();
        tagStack.add(localName);
        if ("[dance]".equals(tagStack.toString()) {
            // populate title and id of dance object from atts
        }
    }

    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, 
    String qName) throws SAXException  {
        String text = buffer.toString().trim();
        switch (tagStack.toString()) {
            case "[dance, type]":
                dance.setType(text);
                break;
            case "[dance, scene]":
                dance.setScene(text);
                break;
            case "[dance, numberOfDancers]":
                dance.setNumberOfDancers(Integer.parseInt(text));
                break;
            case "[dance, music]":
                dance.setMusic(text);
                break;
            case "[dance, dancers, dancer]":
                dance.getDancers().add(text);
                break;
            case "[dance, number]":
                dance.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(text));
                break;
        }
        buffer.clear();       
        tagStack.remove(tagStack.size() - 1);
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) 
    throws SAXException {
        buffer.append(new String(ch, start, length));
    }

    // return populated domain object
    public Dance getDance() { 
        return dance; 
    }
```

}